# Use: Need Javascript code that gets the inner width/height of screen onload into width/height style variables

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to find the `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` of the screen via Javascript, and then place the values into the width and height variables of the body class in the style area (css) of HTML.
For example:

```
<style>
  body { background-image: url("images/hello.jpg"); 
         background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: brown; 
         width: valueW; height: valueH;}
</style>
```

Where `valueW` is the returned value of the pixels of the `innerWidth` of the screen, and `valueH` for `innerHeight`.
The "px" pixels value would need to follow the returned number of course.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Have you read [this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: Why do you need this? Using fixed positioning may be an easier solution for what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the CSS `vh` and `vw` units, which do that automatically.
No Javascript needed.

Comment: How do I use vh and vw in CSS? Sorry I am a newby.